# Track Android App installation via InstallReferrerReceiver in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I am having a play store link to my app in the website built via [Google play store url builder](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#google-play-url-builder) .

Now i want to track those UTM parameters in my firebase analytics when an app get installed and also i want to associate the UTM parameter with the device id of the app. Firebase analytics add network attribution does not have  provision to add custom channel for my website.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the [blogpost](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/04/understanding-attribution-in-firebase.html) on Understanding Attribution in Firebase Analytics.

Scroll down to the section where it says What about Dynamic Links? There you would see how to create a link using UTM parameter and track the attribution on the Analytics Dashboard.